# Widget not appearing directly below scaled widget

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following, the blue container appears inside the scaled amber container. How can I position the blue container to be directly below the scaled amber container without adding any spacing (such as using a `SizedBox`) or repositioned the second widget?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Transform.scale(
                alignment: const Alignment(-1, -1),
                scale: 2,
                child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.amber)),
            Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.blue)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It seems like the size of scaled widget is not taken into account when displaying the second widget.

Comment: you want to blue container exact center of screen?

Comment: That is what's currently displayed. I want the blue container to be directly below the amber container.

Comment: check my answer hope its help to you

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you :

```
   Column(
      children: [
        Container(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.amber,
          ),
        Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your Result Screen -> [image]

Comment: I need to scale the amber widget with the Transform widget. I didn't have the Transform widget in my code by accident.

Comment: ok, you must want to `Transform.scale()`widget

Answer (score 0):

While using `Transform.scale` we are changing the scale of a widget from its current transform. And `Transform`  controls properties like `align`, `size`.... simple way it helps child during painting.

**Black rectangle represent the column-Border**

```dart
 Transform.scale(
          scale: 2,
          child: Container(width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.amber),
        ),
```

As you increase, `scale:2` means it will scale 2x from its current position.
you can read [size vs scale](https://vanseodesign.com/web-design/size-scale-proportion/).

**Image on Scale:2** it is getting 100x100 size, because of using `scale`

[image]

Image of having `scale:2`, black border represent original scale(1x).
Without calling `alignment` property, it will be at centered.

[image]

While applying `alignment: const Alignment(-1, -1)` we are  aligning it at top-left. You can check about [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html).

[image]

Let's add another  container now.

```dart
 Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Transform.scale(
              alignment: const Alignment(-1, -1),
              scale: 2,
              child: Container(
                  width: 100, height: 100, color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(.3)),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.3),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

As we know, `Black represent the column border`, means our 1st `Transform.scale` is painting outside the Column because of using scale property.

[image]

### **Solution Part**

Hope you have got the concept and find way to solve it, here is few

you can add

```dart
SizedBox(
      height: 100 * scale * .5,
     ),
```

Because our actual container height 100  and multiply with have half scale. For scale 2 it will be `height: 100 * 2 * .5,`.

Or you can have margin at second container like

```dart
 Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100 * 2 * .5),
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.3),
            )
```

or you can add bottom margin on `Transform.scale` container like

`margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100 * 2 * .5),`

**Widget to text**

```dart
class TTSW extends StatefulWidget {
  TTSW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TTSWState createState() => _TTSWState();
}

class _TTSWState extends State<TTSW> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        width: 100,
        // height: 100 + 100,

        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.black)),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Transform.scale(
              alignment: const Alignment(-1, -1),
              scale: 2,
              child: Container(
                  // margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 100 * 2 * .5),
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(.3)),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100 * 2 * .5,
            ),
            Container(
             // margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100 * 2 * .5),
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(.93),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );

     
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had solved it by adding a SizedBox between the containers, but I want to know if this can be solved without doing this.

Comment: We are scaling container here,  that's  why there will be overlap because it is not resizing at 2x. You can change the size(height and width) of Container instead of using `Transform.scale`. Scale is just about painting on UI. if it solves, feel free to close the question.